# Include static JS files into Symfony without compiling

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig, assets

I am migrating a website from plain PHP to Symfony 4, with a few of its JS files that I'm trying to include into Twig.

In symfony docs, it is recommended to use Webpack or Assetic. But when I use those libraries, there are some bugs in the render concerning javacript.

So I'd like to migrate my plain static JS files into Symfony without passing by any compiler or module, like that :

```
<script src="{{ asset('build/js/scripts.min.js') }}"></script>
```

But this way, there is still an issue with javascript.
When I'm looking in the source code (*view-source:http://localhost:8000/build/js/scripts.min.js*), the file is starting like this :

```
‹���������������HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: localhost:8000
Date: Thu, 07 Jun 2018 09:46:54 +0000
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Length: 32861

var mr=function(a,b,c){  ... // the rest of js code
```

All my JS files are in *public/build/js* directory.

Is there something I'm missing with the inclusion of static JS files in Symfony ?

Comment: Have you done something like `php bin/console assets:install` ?

Comment: It returns :  [OK] No assets were provided by any bundle.